# Why java fails regex expression

Tags: java, regex

I wrote a condition with regex `str.matches("\\D+")` read with Scanner but on entering char+digit this test fails for example 3x or e3 but it should not happen.
It should pass any non digit occurrence anywhere in the string even if its a symbol.

Comment: Why should it pass? `\D` is a non-digit character.

Comment: atleast once a non digit occurrence should be there thats what i'm saying, should pass.

Comment: "str" is a string read with Scanner class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> atleast once a non digit occurrence should be there thats what i'm saying, should pass

How about this

`.*\D.*`

You can [test it here](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html).

Comment: The non-digit occurrence should occur anywhere, which means you can have anything else before or after. `+`, `1+`, `+1`, `1+1`. You would just replace `.*` with the appropriate regex if `.*` is too broad.

Comment: A good source to read regex, since most of the articles do not split up the examples and explain.

Answer (score 3):

If `m` is a `Matcher`, then `m.matches` returns `true` only if the **entire** string matches the pattern.  If you want to just check whether some part of the string matches, you can use `m.find` instead of `m.matches`.  (Note: I'm not sure whether that's actually the problem you're having.)

Comment: find(), not a JDK method.

Comment: @Prashant It's a method of the `Matcher` class, but you're right, it's not a `String` class method, while `matches` is a method of both.  If you really want to use the `String` version, put `.*` at both ends of the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

This call fails to match `3e` since:

```
str.matches("\\D+")
```

is same as:

```
str.matches("^\\D+$")
```

Because `String#matches` takes given regex and matches the complete input.

To make sure there is at least one non-digit, you should better use this lookahead based regex:

```
str.matches("(?=\\d*\\D).*")
```

Where `(?=\\d*\\D)` is positive lookahead that makes sure there is at least 1 non-digit in the given input.

Answer (score -1):

\D matches any non-numeric character, so of course it will fail if you pass it a string with digits in it.

If you want to match only characters and numbers you could do something like:

```
matches("[a-zA-Z0-9"]+);
```

Comment: i just want to pass a non digit occurrence anywhere in the string even if it is a symbol.